# Airflow Schedule_Interval Crontab syntax

Tags: python, cron, airflow

I want to confirm the correct syntax to perform my python scripts task every Monday at 9AM. Currently my script is set to send every Sunday morning at 12AM    (0 0 * * 0).

Comment: Always remember, on *nix, man is your friend. http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: @user590028 Man provides an example of 5 minutes after midnight. I need every five minutes of the day. To clarify ex. 12:05am 12:10am 12:15am . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a schedule to fire every 5 minutes of the day, use the following "skip" entry of crontab:

```
*/5 * * * *
```